# Navigate to dropdown parent's link on second click in Bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to implement functionality that will allow users to navigate to the href of a dropdown list item's anchor on mobile devices on the second click. However, I only want this to happen if the list item currently has the "open" class, designating that the link currently has been clicked once. I've tried the following:

```
$('.dropdown').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('open')) {
        window.location = $(this).find('a.dropdown-toggle.visible-sm').href();
    }
});
```

and:

```
$('.dropdown.open').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function () {
    window.location = $(this).find('a.dropdown-toggle.visible-sm').href();
});
```

but both cause users to navigate to any other dropdown link's href without expanding the dropdown list. After looking into it some more, I found some articles that say that when a class is dynamically added you need to use event delegation to be able to reference the dynamically-added class. I've tried this:

```
$(document).on('click', 'li.open', function(){
    window.location = $(this).find('a.dropdown-toggle.visible-sm').href();
});
```

but it does the same thing as what I've tried previously.

Comment: Hi,Trying to understand, what do you mean by ' navigate to the href of a dropdown list item's anchor on mobile devices on the second click.'

Comment: Hi Matthew, so basically this navigation will be dynamically created and each of the primary links that contain dropdowns will still have links that they need to be able to navigate to instead of just serving as a container for the sub links. I need to allow users to click a primary link and, if it contains a dropdown, expand the dropdown. If a user clicks another primary link with a dropdown, the first dropdown will slide up and the new one will slide down. If the user clicks the primary link a second time it will take them to the expanded link's href.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to figure this out just in case anyone should ever need to do this:

```
$('.dropdown').on('show.bs.dropdown', function () {
    $(this).siblings('.open').removeClass('open').find('a.dropdown-toggle').attr('data-toggle', 'dropdown');
    $(this).find('a.dropdown-toggle').removeAttr('data-toggle');
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Tony's solution doesn't work out for me, as it becomes impossible to close the dropdown without some extra JavaScript function.

I'm going by opening the page, if the dropdown is already open.

```js
$('.dropdown a.dropdown-toggle').on('click', function() {
    if($(this).parent().hasClass('open'))
        location.assign($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks - that worked nicely for me!  Just to mention that if you have multiple dropdowns you want this behaviour on, adding an id to each anchor link and using that instead of .dropdown a.dropdown-toggle works.

Comment: This still works on Bootstrap 4, however you do need to change 'open' to 'show'.

Answer (score 2):

Working off of [Pendrokar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25846641/409958) I use this to cover all dropdown menus since 'open' is not always assigned as a class and allows for the target to be specified by the link.

```
$('a[data-toggle="dropdown"]:not([href=""])').off('click.namespace').on('click.namespace',
   function(e) {
       if ($(this).parent().is('.show, .open')) 
           window.open($(this).attr(
                'href'), $(this).attr('target') || '_self');
   });
```

Comment: Works with bootstrap 4.4.1