# Make WordPress Bootstrap Parent Menu Link Clickable

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the Hestia Wordpress theme and trying to make the parent menu items clickable. Not sure how best to do this. Below is the code taken from the themes header. Any advice on making these links clickable would be really appreciated.

```
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top <?php echo esc_attr( $navbar_class ); ?>">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-collapse="collapse" data-target="#main-navigation">
                        <span class="sr-only"><?php esc_html_e( 'Toggle Navigation', 'hestia-pro' ); ?></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div class="title-logo-wrapper">
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>"><?php echo hestia_logo(); ?></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php
                    wp_nav_menu( array(
                        'theme_location'    => 'primary',
                        'depth'             => 2,
                        'container'         => 'div',
                        'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
                        'container_id'      => 'main-navigation',
                        'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right',
                        'fallback_cb'       => 'hestia_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
                        'walker'            => new hestia_bootstrap_navwalker(),
                    ) );
                ?>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

Comment: You need to look into hestia_bootstrap_navwalker function / file to find out how the menu is being built and modify to your needs. (Keep in mind using a child theme)

Comment: OK, thank you. I will take a look and see.

Comment: OK I have found the file you suggested, however I am unsure what i should be editing in the PHP code to return the result I am after. Any suggestions would be really useful.

Comment: Can you post that file somewhere and link here?

Comment: I found the answer and have it working now. Thank you for pointing me int he right direction. Here is a link to the code changes

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25692514/bootstrap-how-do-i-make-dropdown-navigation-parent-links-an-active-link

Answer (score 0):

I realize I'm a little late, and that no one (including me) is going to particularly like this answer, but after much attempting to hack the WP menu template and bootstrap core unsuccessfully - I decided to just reattach the click events onload. Yeah it sucks, but it works...

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementById('menu').getElementsByTagName('a')).forEach(function(el){ el.addEventListener('click', function(event){ window.location = event.target.href }) })
})
```

**Change:** 'menu' **in:** document.getElementById('menu') to whatever your menu's main Id is (or change out for getElementsByClassName)

I put this in my actual template header, at the very end of <head> in a <script> tag, but of course you can register it in functions - which is more "correct."

As it turns out it's this stupid attribute causing all the fuss: data-toggle=dropdown, I can't seem to find a direct prevention of it's normal behavior, but I think there are some processes that appear add or modify the menu item logic in bootstrap core, so it could be that all menu items have preventDefault() run on them at some point, and these get eliminated logically from a secondary process to make the link clickable - not sure...