# Bootstrap open link when clicked on dropdown menu button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I used bootstrap in my main menu and since my project has a lot of pages, subpages and sub-subpages I used the bootstrap dropdownmenu to navigate through this.

My client now wants to be able to go to the link associated with the dropdown-button itself too, rather than the childen. My client has text on a page called 'customer support', and text on subpages (children). Ideally I want the user to first click a dropdownmenu button (ex. "Customer service"), and a dropdownmenu opens up (which Bootstrap does), and on a second click be able to go to the link associated with that dropdownmenu button (ex. "/customer-service").

I'll share some code to make it a bit more understandable:

```
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="dropdown"> <a href="/customer-service" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>

                    <!-- click this menu-button once, and the submenu below opens, click this menu-button twice and you go to /customer-service -->
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>

                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kozog9rx/2/

*(be sure to read the comment in the HTML and give the "Result-view" enough space/width so the menu appears)*

Comment: Please share some code, it'll be easier to understand your problem and more expressive that way, than writing about it :)

Comment: I will thank you, sorry for my absense for a few days. I was quite busy with another project :)

Comment: I have changed the title and text of my post to make it more clear. Can you or someone else please have another look at it?

Comment: Just leaving this for anyone who comes in via Google : there's another question about this here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24247970/navigate-to-dropdown-parents-link-on-second-click-in-bootstrap-3  with an answer that worked for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, assuming you are using bootstrap `3.2.0` Here's the code:

```
<li class="dropdown">
   <a href="example.com/page">Dropdown</a>
   <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="caret"></span></a>    
   <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

What i'm doing is making the carat open the menu, and the text `href` to wherever you want it to go to.

Comment: Thank you for your example. I tried it, but it does not quite give the result i was hoping for, because when i run it in my dev. enviroment the users has to click the arrow/caret seperatly to go to the link, and the text "Dropdown" to open the dropdownmenu. I want the user to open the dropdownmenu on the first click on the button, and to go to the link when the user clicks the same menubutton a second time. I believe this can be achieved through JS, but since this is very deep-level Bootstrap and JS i do not have a clue on where to begin.